# Recover data after deleted and formated

Tags: windows-10, windows-8, data-recovery

Well I've searched on this site something equal to my problem and I didn't find any help.

Let's say I had a `keystore.jks` file on my `%User%/KeyStore/` (I was using Windows 8 by the way), then I updated to Windows 10 and I had problems with Visual Studio 2015 and I put the option "Back to Windows 8", and sadly this folder (and more) was removed. What I did is format my Notebook, installed a new Windows 10 and I'm trying to recover that file but I'm not able to.

I've used:

- easy-drive-data
- pci_filerecovery
- Recuva
- Pandorarecovery

And for me didn't work, is this possible to get that file back to my own?

Comment: Did you find any of the files in C:\Windows.old? Rollback doesn't affect personal files, usually your files will just stay as they were before, if you can't recover from Windows.old, try data recovery programs, suggest you EaseUS data recovery. Hope this tutorial can help http://www.howtogeek.com/130558/how-to-restore-your-files-from-the-windows.old-folder-after-upgrading/

Comment: I don't have the `C:\Windows.old`.... :(

Comment: See the Windows.old folder: 
Click Start and in the 'Search' box enter:  "hidden"  (without the quotes). 
Click the "Show hidden files and folders" option at the top of the list.
In the 'Folder Options' Window:
Click of the 'View' if it is not already selected.
In the 'Advanced settings'  list locate 'Hidden files and folders'.
Now click on 'Show hidden files and folders' 
Next uncheck the following:  
'Hide empty drives in the Computer folder'  
'Hide extentions for know file types'. 
'Hide protected operating system file' .
Click the 'Apply' button and the 'OK' button.

Comment: I don't have the `windows.old` een if I follow all of your steps

Comment: Are you sure that you did an upgrade install? when did you upraded to windows 10? windows.old will removed after 30 days.

Comment: Oh, then it's removed... I lost the file 3 months ago I guess...